# How to add images to buttons inside `confirmationDialog`

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm building my first SwiftUI app and I've run into a blocker. When a user long-presses one of my cells, I want to show a `confirmationdialog` with custom buttons.

Here's the code:

```
.confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showLongPressMenu) {
    Button {
        //
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
            Text("Add completion")
        }
    }
    Button {
        //
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "note.text.badge.plus")
            Text("Add Note")
        }
    }
    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
}
```

This is sort-of working, here's the result:

[image]

But what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Any pointers would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: Currently that is not possible with either `UIKit` or `SwiftUI`. You'll have to create a custom `View` suiting your need.

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter Ah ok, shoot. Thanks very much. I'll try find out how to do that.

Comment: FWIW, this can be done with UIKit with: `action.setValue(UIImage(systemName: "camera"), forKey: "image")` where action is a UIAlertAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick pure `SwiftUI` custom `Dialog` I wrote using `resultBuilder` avoiding the `Divider` approach:

Package URL: https://github.com/NoeOnJupiter/ComplexDialog/

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var color = Color.green
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("This is a Test")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }.padding(20)
        .background(color)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous))
        .presentDialog(isPresented: $isPresented, bodyContent: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text("Red Color")
                Spacer()
            }.dialogAction {
                color = .red
            }
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text("Blue Color")
                Spacer()
            }.dialogAction {
                color = .blue
            }
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                Text("Green Color")
                Spacer()
            }.dialogAction {
                color = .green
            }
        }, cancelContent: {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Cancel")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Spacer()
            }.dialogAction {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Good effort! tried it out. It would be great your solution had the title and message. Also found out that we can't reorder the Spacer or image.  for example Have the images at the trailing end and have a Spacer in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach I'm working on:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showConfirmationDialog = false
    @State private var showModifierDialog = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Dialog") { showConfirmationDialog = true }
            Button("Show ViewMod Dialog") {
                withAnimation {
                    showModifierDialog = true
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
        
        // standard confirmationDialog
        .confirmationDialog("Test", isPresented: $showConfirmationDialog) {
            Button { } label: {
                Label("Add completion", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
            }
            Button { } label: {
                Label("Add Note", systemImage: "note.text.badge.plus")
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
        }
        
        // custom confirmationDialog with Icons, Cancel added automatically
        .customConfirmDialog(isPresented: $showModifierDialog) {
            Button {
                // action
                showModifierDialog = false
            } label: {
                Label("Add completion", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
            }
            Divider() // unfortunately this is still necessary
            Button {
                // action
                showModifierDialog = false
            } label: {
                Label("Add Note", systemImage: "note.text.badge.plus")
            }
        }
    }
}


// *** Custom ConfirmDialog Modifier and View extension

extension View {
    func customConfirmDialog<A: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder actions: @escaping () -> A) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(MyCustomModifier(isPresented: isPresented, actions: actions))
    }
}

struct MyCustomModifier<A>: ViewModifier where A: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder let actions: () -> A
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                if isPresented {
                    Color.primary.opacity(0.2)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .onTapGesture {
                                isPresented = false
                        }
                        .transition(.opacity)
                }
                
                if isPresented {
                    VStack {
                        GroupBox {
                            actions()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        
                        GroupBox {
                            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                                    isPresented = false
                            }
                            .bold()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(8)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: isPresented)
   }
}
```